# Can't get @ViewById to work inside an @EBean

Tags: android, android-annotations

```
  @EActivity(R.layout.data_layout) 
   public class MyActivity extendsActivity 
   {    
     @Bean    MyEbean bean;

      @AfterViews    
      public void setupView() 
      {
        bean.loadData("Test name");    
      } 
    }

   @EBean public class MyEbean 
   {    
     @RootContext    context;

      @ViewById(R.id.name_field)    
      TextView nameField;

     public void loadData(String name) 
     {
       nameField.setText(name);   
     } 
}
```

"nameField" in loadData() is null. At the same time if I do this inside    loadData()

```
nameField = (TextView)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.name_field);       it's all good. So the view isdefinitely there. Also if I call this method from a retrofit callback
```

(i.e. after a delay) "name" is auto populated.

I'm using Android Annotations 3.3.2

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason why it doesn't work but if you need it just works, the solution is pretty easy:

```java
@EActivity(R.layout.data_layout) 
public class MyActivity extends Activity {    
    @Bean    MyEbean bean; 
}

@EBean
public class MyEbean {
    @ViewById Button previewButton;

    @AfterViews void init() {
        previewButton.setText("Blah");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-Agree with above answer

The **key point** is ....

```
 @AfterViews void init() {
    previewButton.setText("Blah");
}
```

- this shows that views are fetched so you will not get null pointer .